# VBA Worksheet Sub Create Named Range in Another Worksheet

Tags: vba, excel

I have a private sub that needs to create named ranges within another worksheet. It needs to stay a worksheet function, as it is a `Worksheet_Change` sub. I have successfully been able to set a range variable equal to a range on another sheet with this line:

```
Set rng2 = Sheets("Lists").Range(Sheets("Lists").Cells(2, Col), Sheets("Lists").Cells(Unique, Col))
```

However, when I put `rng2` into the other portion of my code, it simply refers to the correct range within the Active Sheet.

Here is what I have tried:

```
ActiveWorkbook.Names.Add Name:="Level" & Col, RefersTo:= _
    "= " & Sheets("Lists").Range(Sheets("Lists").Cells(2, Col), Sheets("Lists").Cells(Unique, Col)).Address & ""
```

and:

```
ActiveWorkbook.Names.Add Name:="Level" & Col, RefersTo:= _
    "=" & rng2.Address & ""
```

The bottom function works when it is within a module stored inside the workbook as a whole, but again, does not work within a worksheet sub.
I have also tried `Sheets("Lists").rng2.Address` in the bottom attempt.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To have the address include the sheet's name, you have to set the `external` parameter:

```
rng2.address(external:=True)
```

Comment: Nice, I didn't know that! Hope you don't mind I tweaked that part of my answer ++

Comment: @CallumDA had I seen your answer I would have suggested this in a comment. No problem. :)

Comment: I'm getting a whole bunch of errors. A bit more context would be useful.

Answer (score 3):

Your `RefersTo` string needs to be something like `"=Lists!A1"`. So all it's missing is the reference to the lists worksheet.

Try something like this:

```
Dim wsLists As Worksheet
Set wsLists = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Lists")

With wsLists
    Set rng2 = .Range(.Cells(2, Col), .Cells(Unique, Col))
    ThisWorkbook.Names.Add Name:="Level" & Col, RefersTo:="=" & rng2.Address(external:=True)
End With
```